# Setting properties (like date format, time format etc.) for a worklight app from another worklight app in same project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Can I set some properties for a worklight app from another worklight app, in the same project ?

I want to make one configuration app which configures properties, like date format/time format/enabling-disabling some functionalities etc, for different worklight applications in the same project.

Is that possible?

Comment: Be more descriptive. Are you looking to remotely manage your application's various functionalities from another application?

Comment: Not remotely but locally. 
The idea is to edit properties of all the other apps using this configuration app. The app has to work locally without worklight server connectivity and it must be possible for other apps also to fetch those properties locally (i.e. without WL server connectivity).

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674477/worklight-6-2-share-info-between-apps-family -- whatever the solution is, you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Hey thanks. I think this is what i was looking for.

I 'll just go through this.

Comment: There is a bug in the Simple Data Sharing API.
Description given in the link below.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674477/worklight-6-2-share-info-between-apps-family

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this, but there is nothing built-in or existing that does this.
Whatever you do will have to go through the Worklight Server and not peer-to-peer.

Here's what you could possibly do (you'll need to actually implement it and see how feasible it is):
Note that this is highly simplified; it's just general steps.

**User application**

1. Application launches
2. User logs-in
3. Upon successful log-in, invoke some "RemoteControl" adapter procedure, "applySettings".
4. By default this will return a pre-defined configuration, a set of application settings that the client logic will know how to apply. Like some JSON object containing key:value pairs that you will apply logic based on them.

Since all client applications will connect to the Worklight Server, they are thus registered in the database with the user identity.

**Controller application**

5. In the Controller application, you will be able to retrieve a list of all registered users as well as retrieve the settings that are set for each of the listed users, using the "RemoteControl" adapter procedure "retrieveRegisteredUsersAndSettings".
6. Devise some UI for all users and the available settings and checkboxes etc which will be marked with whichever settings are enabled or disabled per user.
7. Have another procedure in the same "RemoteControl" adapter, "setSettings". This will store the user settings in the database

When the user logs-in, these same set settings from step 6 are applied instead of the previous default (now changed...) settings in step 3.

**Notes:**

- You could also have it so the procedure will be invoked whenever doing any sort of request to the server rather than only after log-in. Purely applicative.
- If you have more than 1 application, you could also save in the database using userPrefs which app the logged-in user uses and the retrieve this information as well in the controller application; you can then sort the display of all of this information in the UI.

Comment: What if there is no connectivity with the worklight server or I want to use it in offline mode. 

Is there any workaround by which I can keep a local JSON file whose values I can edit using Configuration app and other apps can fetch those values without connecting to the worklight server ?

Comment: Read about using JSONStore. You have a lot of implementation to do.

Comment: I did. We can not access the JSON store of one app from another app in the same project.

Comment: Well, obviously. Go through the database.